# Ориентация android экрана для планшета

Tags: java, android

Как сделать, чтобы активити запускалось на смартфонах в `landscape` ориентации, а на планшетах в `portrait`?

P.S. Я устанавливаю ориентацию через манифест `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Answer (score 4):

Можете попробовать так:

```
public static int getSwDp(Activity activity){
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int swDp = (int) ScreenHelper.convertPixelsToDp(wt, activity);
    return swDp;
}

if (getSwDp(activity)<=600) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}else{
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

Вы берете сначала минимальную ширину экрана в `dp`, после чего смотрите, соответствует ли она минимальной ширине для которой вы хотите показывать горизонтальную разметку  и устанавливаете ориентацию.

P.S. я этот код не тестировал, но должно работать!

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое
Получаем ширину экрана, если больше 600 то Landscape, если нет то Portrait.

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```